# angular-sanitize and angular-cookies CVE warnings in google play console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, android-security

Google Play Console now has a list of potentially vulnerable javascript libraries for each app.

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9464300

However, I am not able to find the related CVE for a couple of the libraries that it has flagged. Notably:

- `angular-cookies`, which is a dependency of `angularLocalStorage`
- `angular-sanitize` which is a dependency of `angular-translate`

https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=angular

There is a CVE for `textAngular-sanitize.js`. Is that the reason there is a false positive for `angular-sanitize`?

There are also no vulnerabilities listed in the page for `ngSanitize`, which is part of the AngularJS core libraries.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/api/ngSanitize

I am filing this question because the support page says

> If you have technical questions about the vulnerability, you can post to Stack Overflow and use the tag “android-security.”